# paypal sandbox : "This transaction cannot be completed"

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm in sandbox mode, for recurring billings on Magento.
Parameters are ok and Magento redirects me to the Paypal sandbox to pay and register my recurring billing on "facilitator account's test store".

I log in with my personal test account (declared previously on https://developer.paypal.com). Log in is ok, then paypal display "wait a moment, transaction in progress"
and then I receive "This transaction cannot be completed" (on the sandbox site).

Page displaying this message : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/fr/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=FJk_8RO48KhxhbIbfExJ0pobWexReIjA9vKt6AoOP5QmGWNbMMGQU4MAW-e&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198cf7658296ddbf66bbd0b039a3775ce6f

I did not receive anything else.

How can I fix this ? is there an IP limit on sandbox ?

Comment: Can you try to clear the cookies and cache of your browser and then try again?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, even after clearing all browsing data or using incognito mode. Seems the sandbox servers are having some hiccups right now.

Comment: Are you on local? your ip is public?

Comment: i work on a test website. My IP is public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the customer e-mail address used in the order have problems at PayPal.
Try to use a completely (even unreal) e-mail address for customer.

Also consider creating a Business Account at developer.paypal.com, instead a Facilitator account.

Another point to look at, is *how you are getting your credentials*. If you get your credentials using that button from Magento admin, try to get it in a different way, going directly into your developer's dashboard and clicking on the account *profile* link, used at your magento configuration (see image).

I hope one of these suggestions helps you.

[image]